# Converting day+month into the most recent, matching Date

Tags: java

how can I convert a given Day+Month (given as String) into the most recent date matching that day+month, e.g. "21.1." into 21-01-2018 and "13.1." into 13-01-2019.

I'm using this deprecated solution right now:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date currentDate = new Date();
Date date = df.parse(input + "2016"); // else the 29.02. is never recognized, because in the default parse year 1970 it doesn't exist.
date.setYear(currentDate.getYear()); // deprecated
if (date.compareTo(currentDate) > 0) {
    date.setYear(currentDate.getYear() - 1);
}
return date;
```

Comment: Your handling of leap year is odd, it will still return 2016 even after the we passed 29.2 the next leap year.

Comment: See my answer for a more future-proof handling of 29th of February.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version using `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` instead of older classes

```
public LocalDate getDate(String input) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.M.yyyy");
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(String.format("%s.%d", input, now.get(ChronoField.YEAR)), dtf);

    if (date.compareTo(now) > 0) {
        date = date.minusYears(1);
    }
    return date;
}
```

---

Below is a version that will pick the previous 29th of February if `input` is "29.2", I have only tested it briefly but it seems to work.

```
public static LocalDate getDate(String input) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.M.yyyy");
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    boolean is29 = input.equals("29.2");

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(String.format("%s.%d", input, now.get(ChronoField.YEAR)), dtf);

    if (date.compareTo(now) > 0) {
        date = date.minusYears(1);
    }

    if (is29 && !date.isLeapYear()) {
        do {
            date = date.minusYears(1);
        } while (!date.isLeapYear());
        date = date.plusDays(1); //move from 28th to 29th
    }

    return date;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer made me look more deeply into the java.time library and I think I found an even more idiomatic solution through that (see below).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Calendar` to get rid of the deprecated solution :

```
static Date getDate(String input) throws ParseException {

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM");
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setTime(df.parse(input));
    date.set(Calendar.YEAR, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    if (date.after(currentDate)) {
        date.set(Calendar.YEAR, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1);
    }
    return date.getTime();

}
```

Comment: I just realized that the code fails with "29.02" because of the leapyear problem. I edited my question to fix that behaviour, you might wanna do the same in your answer.

Comment: in this case, what is the problem? it return `March 01` because the calendar is lenient

Comment: It will always return March 01 (even if the current or previous year is a leapyear), because the information, that it originally was the 29.02, not the 01.03., is lost when switching from Date to Calendar (if I understood it correctly).

Comment: `Calendar` is considered obsolete, you should use classes from the new Date and Time API (from the `java.time` package).

Answer (score 0):

There is a class `java.time.MonthDay` which works similiar to LocalDate, but without a year:

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM."));
MonthDay today = MonthDay.now();
if (md.isAfter(today)) {
    return Year.now().minusYears(1).atMonthDay(md);
} else {
    return Year.now().atMonthDay(md);
}
```